# How can I make an image rotate certain degrees whenever I click the button? (webkit)

Tags: webkit, rotation, degrees

This is the code:

See I need it to rotate it by `45°` every time I click a button:
0 to 45 - 45 to 90 - 90 to 135 etc etc etc and infinitely.

It would be awesome if you guys help me out.

```
<style type="text/css">
.classname {
-webkit-animation-name: cssAnimation;
-webkit-animation-duration:0.7s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
0% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
95% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(46deg); }
100% {-webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(45deg); }
}

</style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
       function ani(){
            document.getElementById('img').className ='classname';
        }
  </script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body align="center">

 <form  type="button" onclick="ani()"  style="position:relative;z-index:2" name="img" >

<img  src="2.png" width="645" height="545" style="position:absolute;left:26.9%;top:-8%;z-index:1;"/>
```

Comment: You'll have to use some JS since there isn't a CSS click selector. I suppose you could use `:focus` though...

Comment: I'm really tired, so I can't do much more than this tonight, but here's a starting point for you: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/tvQNH/

Comment: Thank you very very much, Im very tired too, That code will help me solve my situation! Thanks again, goodnight.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a fully working solution, mostly because it doesn't know how to handle when the rotation passes 180 degrees. You'll have to figure that out:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var matrix = $("img").css("-webkit-transform");
    var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
    var a = values[0];
    var b = values[1];
    var current = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
    var newz = current + 45;
    $("img").css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(" + newz + "deg)");
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/tvQNH/

Comment: hey charlie, you know that if in the same page another image is put, for example as a top layer of that image (covering this rotating image) it will rotate as well, how do i prevent that from happening??? I'm freaking out with this homework haha

Comment: Change `$("img")` to just the element you want to rotate. Also, if you find this as an acceptable answer, accept it.